# Why is the `message` for my Jest custom matcher not being displayed?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, prisma

I've created a Jest custom matcher. It works (meaning, it passes/fails when it should), but I don't see the `message` anywhere in Jest's output.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to do something to "enable" messages? Am I totally misunderstanding where the message is supposed to show up?

Environment: NestJS, Prisma

Execution command: `jest --watch`

Simplified code:

```js
    declare global {
        namespace jest {
            interface Matchers<R> {
                toMatchHash(received: string, expected: string): R;
            }
        }
    }

    expect.extend({
        toMatchJsonHash(received, expected) {
            return {
                pass: false,
                message: () => `Why doesn't this work?!`,
            };
        },
    });
```

```js
expect(prisma.name.findMany).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.toMatchJsonHash('db0110285c148c77943f996a17cbaf27'));
```

Output:

```
  ● MyService › should pass a test using a custom matcher

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: toMatchJsonHash<db0110285c148c77943f996a17cbaf27>
    Received: {<Big ol' object redacted for conciseness>}

    Number of calls: 1

      178 |
      179 |         // @ts-ignore
    > 180 |         expect(prisma.name.findMany).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.toMatchJsonHash('db0110285c148c77943f996a17cbaf27'));
          |                                      ^
      181 |         // expect(prisma.name.findMany).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      182 |     //   select: { type: true, name: true },
      183 |     //   where: {

      at Object.<anonymous> (my/my.service.spec.ts:180:32)
```

I'm expecting to see "Why doesn't this work?!" somewhere in the output, but I don't. What am I missing?

Comment: The matcher that gets to show a message is `.toHaveBeenCalledWith`, try `expect(some).toMatchHash(other)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That has GOT to be it! Makes perfect sense!Im still “sleeping”, though; excited to try in the morning. Using that approach, how does ‘toMatchHash()’ get access to the “call” info (arguments), though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested by @jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222617/why-is-the-message-for-my-jest-custom-matcher-not-being-displayed#comment124138323_70222617), the reason was that Jest was showing the message from the "outer" matcher, `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()`.

To fix this, I found [the source that defines the `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` matcher](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e0b33b74b5afd738edc183858b5c34053cfc26dd/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L547) and "merged" its code into my custom matcher.

This enabled my custom matcher to effectively "extend" the functionality of the `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` matcher, including my own custom code and messages.

In case it helps someone, the code I ended up with for my specific use case was:

```js
declare global {
    namespace jest {
        interface Matchers<R> {
            toHaveBeenCalledWithObjectMatchingHash(expected: string): CustomMatcherResult;
        }
    }
}

expect.extend({toHaveBeenCalledWithObjectMatchingHash(received, expected) {
        const isSpy = (received: any) =>
            received != null &&
            received.calls != null &&
            typeof received.calls.all === 'function' &&
            typeof received.calls.count === 'function';
        
        const receivedIsSpy = isSpy(received);
        const receivedName = receivedIsSpy ? 'spy' : received.getMockName();

        const calls = receivedIsSpy
            ? received.calls.all().map((x: any) => x.args)
            : received.mock.calls;
        
        if(calls.length === 0) {
            return {
                pass: false,
                message: () => `expected the function to be called with an object that hashes to '${expected}'. Instead, the function was not called.`,
            };
        }

        if(calls[0].length === 0) {
            return {
                pass: false,
                message: () => `expected the function to be called with an object that hashes to '${expected}'. Instead, the function was called, but not with any arguments.`,
            };
        }

        const md5Hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
        const receivedHash = md5Hash.update(JSON.stringify(calls[0][0])).digest('hex');
        const pass = receivedHash === expected;
        
        if(pass) {
            return {
                pass: true,
                message: () => `expected the function to not be called with an object that hashes to '${expected}'. Instead, the passed object hashes to the same value.`,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                pass: false,
                message: () => `expected the function to be called with an object that hashes to '${expected}'. Instead, the passed object hashes to '${receivedHash}'.`,
            };
        }
    }});
```